# What is int8_t if a machine has > 8 bits per byte?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was reading the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/intrinsic-types.html) and it says

> The C++ language guarantees a byte must always have at least 8 bits

So what does that mean for the `<cstdint>` types?

Side question - if I want an array of bytes should I use `int8_t` or `char` and why?

Comment: Technically it's a C question, as the types are referred back to the C standard (§7.18).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

C++ (and C as well) defines `intX_t` (i.e. the exact width integer types) typedefs as *optional*. So, it just won't be there if there is no addressable unit that's exactly 8-bit wide.

If you want an array of bytes, you should use `char`, as `sizeof char` (and `signed char` and `unsigned char`) is well-defined to always be 1 byte.

Comment: Wait, if I recall correctly sizeof char is defined to be 1, but the standard doesn't specify wheter it's 1 byte or something else

Comment: @BlackBear: No, the standard is very clear. `sizeof` returns size in bytes, and `sizeof(char) == 1`.

Comment: How the hell do I handle IO across systems with different sized bytes? Or should I not even try?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `unsigned char` if you want to use it as a byte?

Comment: @Xeo: a byte in C++ dooesn't need to be unsigned.

Comment: @Dave: XML is a popular choice.

Comment: @Dave: Usually, you don't, since the overwhelming majority of computers these days use 8-bit bytes.

Comment: +1. Also worth noting `int_least8_t` which is required on all platforms to be the smallest integer type with not less than 8 significant bits.

Comment: Depending on the computer architecture, a byte may consist of 8 or more bits, the exact number being recorded in CHAR_BIT. So char is not always 8 bit

Comment: @Dave, for portable I/O use text. It is possible to handle binary data in C/C++, but adhering to some externally defined binary format *is* painful.

Comment: @Dave Well, at least in the case of POSIX, every I/O is well defined in terms of POSIX's bytes, which are themselves exactly 8 bits, see 3.84 at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html. The manual page for read() doesn't explcitly says so, but when doing I/O one unit of 8 bits will be assignated to one C/C++ byte. See the example code at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html

Comment: @Bill and how to get the XML file from on system to a other? The Problem are at the level of hardware interfaces (like how many bits per frame and can we (in case of bigger frames, such as ethernet, in contrast to a UART) split a frame in bytes), but there are solvable.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I was answering from the perspective of an applications developer - I have a file I need to get from machine A to B. I could care about bit/byte level encoding, or I could use a library for something like XML that has already solved the problem. If you are the one writing the low level libraries, then no, something like XML isn't an answer.

Answer (score 2):

To add to what Cat Plus Plus has already said (that the type is
optional), you can test whether it is present by using something like:

```
#ifdef INT8_MAX
//  type int8_t exists.
#endif
```

or more likely:

```
#ifndef INT8_MAX
#error Machines with bytes that don't have 8 bits aren't supported
#endif
```

Comment: A compiler can define `int8_t` and do calculation in software while the machine is not 8 bits per byte.

Comment: I'm not sure about that.  I think that `int8_t` is supposed to be a typedef to one of the basic integral types.  But I'm not sure.  Such an implementation would be very slow on a machine with 9 bit 1's complement (some Unisys).

Comment: @JamesKanze, that's exactly why you should use the "native" types whenever possible.

Comment: @vonbrand That is exactly my argument.  The default type for integral values is `int`.  Anything else should only be used in special cases.