# Under what circumstances would one use a signed char in C++?

Tags: c++, char

In most situations, one would declare a `char` object to assign one of the character values on the ascii table ranging from 0 - 127. Even the extended character sets range from 128 - 255 (still positive). So i'm assuming that when dealing with the printing of characters, one only needs to use an `unsigned char`.

Now, based on some research on SO, people use a `signed char` when they need to use really small integers, but for that we can utilize the `[u]int8` type. So i'm having trouble coming to terms with why one would need to use a `signed char` ? You can use it if you are dealing with the basic character ascii table (which `unsigned char` is already capable of doing) or you can use it to represent small integers (which `[u]int8` already takes care of).

Can someone please provide a programming example in which a `signed char` is preferred over the other types ?

Comment: I think it's worth noting that `[u]int8_t` [was introduced with C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) - it's possible `signed char` was what people used before the introduction of C++11, or still use if their compiler doesn't fully support it.

Comment: You're right, I can't think of a single instance where `signed char` would be preferred over `unsigned char` or `int8_t`. I think we're stuck with it for historical reasons however.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. You would use a signed char when you need to represent a quantity in the range [-128, 127] and you can't (for whatever reason) spare more than a single byte to do it. Is this not straightforward?

Comment: @Jon The point OP is making is that an `int8_t` takes up a single byte as well, so why use `signed char` instead?

Comment: @computerfreaker: Why would you use A over B when they do the exact same thing? Because. Note that your question can easily be reversed: why use `int8_t` instead? It should be clear that there is no proper answer to any of the two forms.

Comment: "[W]hen dealing with the printing of characters, one only needs to use an `unsigned char`."  This is an incorrect assumption.  Plain `char` may be signed or unsigned depending on the implementation.  When printing characters, you can simply use `char` and assume that the implementation does the right thing, even if `char`s are signed on your platform.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Although I agree that it does the right thing, I still don't like the idea that I don't know if `'\x77'` is greater or smaller than `'\x88'` in other compilers than my own.

Comment: @Jon Why? Because one has a name that describes it as a _character_ type, while the other has a name that describes it as an eight-bit type. They may have identical behaviour, but the fact that C and C++ conflate the concepts of "byte" and "character" doesn't mean there's no reason to use one over the other. For example, I use `int8_t` when I mean "small integer," `uint8_t` when I mean "byte," and `char` when I mean "character." I think the real question here is "What does it mean for a character to be (un)signed?" and the answer is "It means that `char` also means 'byte.'"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The reason is that you don't know, at least portably, if plain `char` variables are signed or unsigned. Different implementations have different approaches, a plain `char` may be signed in one platform and unsigned in another.

If you want to store negative values in a variable of type `char`, you absolutely must declare it as `signed char`, because only then you can be sure that every platform will be able to store negative values in there. Yes, you can use `[u]int8` type, but this was not always the case (it was only introduced in C++11), and in fact, `int8` is most likely an alias for `signed char`.

Moreover, `uint8_t` and `int8_t` are defined to be *optional* types, meaning you can't always rely on its existence (contrary to `signed char`). In particular, if a machine has a byte unit with more than 8 bits, it is not very likely that `uint8_t` and `int8_t` are defined (although they can; a compiler is always free to provide it and do the appropriate calculations). See this related question: [What is int8_t if a machine has > 8 bits per byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509453/what-is-int8-t-if-a-machine-has-8-bits-per-byte)

Comment: Can't really see a reason for the downvote, besides need to be more precise about `[u]int8_t`

Answer (score 13):

**Is `char` *signed* or *unsigned*?**

Actually it is neither, it's implementation defined if a variable of type `char` can hold negative values. So if you are looking for a portable way to store negative values in a *narrow character type* explicitly declare it as `signed char`.

> § 3.9.1 - **Fundamental Types** - `[basic.fundamental]`
>
> > <sup>1</sup> Objects declared as characters (`char`) shall be large enough to store any member of the implementation's basic character set. If a character from this set is stored in a character object, the integral value of that character object is equal to the value of the single character literal form of that character. **It is implementation-defined whether a `char` object can hold negative values**.

---

**I'd like to use the smallest *signed integer type* available, which one is it?**

c++11 introduced several fixed with integer types, but a common misunderstanding is that these types are guaranteed to be available, something which **isn't** true.

> § 18.4.1 - **Header `<cstdint>` synopsis** - `[cstdint.syn]`
>
> > `typedef`*`signed integer type`*`int8_t; // optional`

<sub>To preserve space in this post most of the section has been left out, but the *optional* rationale applies to all `{,u}int{8,16,32,64}_t` types. An implementation is **not** required to implement them.</sub>

---

The standard mandates that `int_least8_t` is available, but as the name implies this type is only guaranteed to have a width **equal or larger** than 8 bits.

However, the standard guarantees that even though `signed char`, `char`, and `unsigned char` are three distinct types<sup>[1]</sup> they must occupy the same amount of storage and have the same alignment requirements.

After inspecting the standard further we will also find that `sizeof(char)` is **guaranteed** to be `1`<sup>[2]</sup> , which means that this type is guaranteed to occupy the smallest amount of space that a C++ variable can occupy under the given implementation.

---

**Conclusion**

Remember that `unsigned char` and `signed char` must occupy the same amount of storage as a `char`?

The smallest *signed integer type* that is guaranteed to be available is therefore `signed char`.

---

---

<sup>[**note 1**]</sup>

> § 3.9.1 - **Fundamental Types** - `[basic.fundamental]`
>
> > <sup>1</sup> Plain `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are **three distinct types**, collectively called narrow character types.
> >
> > A `char`, a `signed char`, and an `unsigned char` **occupy the same amount of storage and have the same alignment requirements** (`3.11`); that is, they have the same object representation. For narrow character types, all bits of the object representation participate in the value representation.

<sup>[**note 2**]</sup>

> § 5.3.3 - **Sizeof** - `[expr.sizeof]`
>
> > `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(signed char)`, and `sizeof(unsigned char)` are 1.
> >
> > The result of `sizeof` applied to any other fundamental type (3.9.1) is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `char` for arithmetic operations with small integers. `unsigned char` will give you greater range, while `signed char` will give you a smaller absolute range and the ability to work with negative numbers.

There are situations where `char`'s small size is of importance and is preffered for these operations, [see here](http://ideone.com/7sStFn), so when one has negative numbers to deal with, `signed char` is the way to go.

Comment: What those situations might be?

Comment: Embedded systems where data registers are 8-bits wide, like a UART.

Comment: Technically, the ranges of unsigned char and char are the same size: both store a range of 256 values (assuming 8-bit chars).

Comment: Yes, that's why I say a smaller **absolute** range

Comment: The sizeof(unsigned char) and sizeof(signed char) seems to be the same on most important architectures. It looks like the argument "There are situations where char's small size is of importance and is preffered for these operation" doesn't apply here

Comment: @user2286810 `sizeof` is the same on all platforms. The size argument has to do with choosing between  an **integer** type and **char** (the latter will aa be smaller). Iff char is your choice, the signed version is your only option if you're dealing with negative numbers